# Is this jump video edited (time reversed)?

Tags: video-editor, webvideos

I'm under the impression that [the jump around minute 2:35](https://youtu.be/ZITh-XIikgI?t=155) of Aaron Johnson in the official video of R.E.M. - ÜBerlin is fake, because I believe it contradicts the physical principle of how human bodies jump up against earth gravity.

On the other hand I guess it is likely obvious that it is has been reversed by video editing from an original scene where he was jumping down and not up. Is there any way or tools to confirm or debunk my hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

By comparing the [original 5 second scene](https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1198656433409134593/pu/vid/640x360/OV4IrjmpXgi3C8cL.mp4), with the [time reversed video](https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1198657530039283713/pu/vid/640x360/vTK0KMXRSZCAHNtl.mp4), produced by [kapwing reverse video online](https://www.kapwing.com/tools/reverse-video), it's apparent that the last one is the natural and realistic movement.